# Was it really necessary to take such precautions to confine Misa

Tags: death-note

They rendered Misa completely immobile and blindfolded her and kept her like this for  40 days. Physically, she wasn't a threat to anyone and she couldn’t  have possibly broken out of the cell. Even if she could kill with only a face, they could have worn masks to cover their faces whenever they interacted with her in person. I just think It is a little inhume to have someone strapped down for 24 hours a day, for 6 weeks, whislt blindfolded at the same time, espically when it was completely uncessary to take such measures.

Answer (score 5):

**They did not know it was unnecessary.** At that point in time they did not know how she was able to kill. She might have been able to kill by mere touch for all they knew. So to be safe, they confined her. This does not look too inhumane and standard practise to me, considering the situation. Keep in mind that despite her being a cute idol, she was also a serial killer and had murdered their companion Ukita. L was not going to take any chances losing another human life.

[image]

After reading chapter 33 again, it seems like L himself never really explained why he confined her this way, other than

> She's suspected of being the second Killer, so it's only logical to restrain her this way.

[image]

Comment: "They did not know it was unnecessary. At that point in time they did not know how

Comment: @user31418 What do you mean, with that quote?

Comment: Sorry. I tried to quote you but something is wrong with my computer and my full reply did not come out.  What I meant to say was... "But how she killed was irrelevant. It is impossible for her to kill without a name and a face. As long as she doesn't she them or know their names, they would have been safe"

Comment: @user31418 How does L know she is physically not a threat? He knew she only needed a face to kill **from a distance**, but seeing as she clearly had supernatural powers, how did he know, she would not able to kill by touching someone for example? She is a mass murderer and would kill anybody in her path, so you need to take as much precautions as possible. I don't understand how you can defend a mass murderer like her...

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was going to write when I clicked on this question. At this time L knew almost nothing about how Misa killed, so he took every precaution. Her restraints are comparable to those used on Hannibal Lecter in Silence of the Lambs, who didn't even have supernatural powers, so given how dangerous she was, this level of caution seems entirely warranted

Comment: Again, she needs a face and their name to kill them. Without those, she is utterly powerless.

Comment: @user31418 What she really needs is the Death Note. Without it she is utterly powerless even if she has a face and name. But again, **L DOES NOT KNOW THIS**.

Comment: It is irrelevant if L knows or not. He knows she cannot kill without a face and a name. Hence, the precautions he took are moot. As long as they kept their faces covered whenever they interacted without her, they are safe.

Comment: @user31418 The precautions are not only done for their own safety. I can see two more reasons why he did it. 1. To prevent her from committing suicide, before they get answers. 2. To mentally break her down, to get answers faster.